# Formatting as posixct if information on day of the month is missing

Tags: r, date, format, posixct

I am having some problems with as.POSIXct().

Giving a vector as an example:
`Dates <- c("2015-01 00","2015-01 01","2015-01 02","2015-01 03","2015-01 04","2015-01 05")`

As you can see I have Information on the year, month and hour (but not on the day of the months).
I do not know what I am doing wrong but using `as.POSIXct(Dates,"%Y-%m %H",tz="GMT")`only creates a bunch of NA's.

Any solution is highly apperciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can insert a day, e.g. first day of the month (as `Date` needs day as well) with `sub` and then use `as.POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct(sub("\\s", "-01 ", Dates), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")
#[1] "2015-01-01 00:00:00 EST" "2015-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "2015-01-01 02:00:00 EST" "2015-01-01 03:00:00 EST" "2015-01-01 04:00:00 EST"
#[6] "2015-01-01 05:00:00 EST"
```